# Delete ranges after function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I have to clear some ranges after having sent an email (That contains a PDF of the sheet), but I can't get it to work.
Because the sheet is being used on a tablet I have had to make a dropdown menu and add a trigger to make it run.
I've tried to move some code around that is supposed to clear the ranges. If I put it into the `print()` function (listed below) it clears the ranges before the PDF is made. If I put it into the `checkSheet()` function (also listed below) it doesn't clear at all (although it does send the email).

**Script without the clearing code.**

```
function onEdit(e) { // Gets called once an edit is made. B6 is the dropdown menu.
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B6') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      e.range.clear({ formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true });
      eval(e.value)();      
    }
  }
}

function print() { // Calls checkSheet() because else it does not work. I do not know why it doesn't work without print()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkSheet").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onEdit().create();
}
  
function checkSheet() { // Creates PDF and sends mail
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/edit");
  const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E4").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();
  const subject = 'Varebestilling' +Date();
  const body = "Varebestilling" +Date();
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' + 
    '&fitw=true' + 
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false' + 
    '&gid=0'; 
 
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf", //add ss
      content: response.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    }]
         
  }); 
}
```

**Script when I put the clearing code in the print function (clears and sends email but in the wrong order).**

```
function onEdit(e) { // Gets called once an edit is made. B6 is the dropdown menu.
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B6') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      e.range.clear({ formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true });
      eval(e.value)();      
    }
  }
}

function print() { // Calls checkSheet() because else it does not work. I do not know why it doesn't work without print()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkSheet").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onEdit().create();
  var rangesToClear = ['B12:B17', 'B20:B25', 'B29:B34'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}
  
function checkSheet() { // Creates PDF and sends mail
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/edit");
  const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E4").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();
  const subject = 'Varebestilling' +Date();
  const body = "Varebestilling" +Date();
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' + 
    '&fitw=true' + 
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false' + 
    '&gid=0'; 
 
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf", //add ss
      content: response.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    }]
         
  }); 
}
```

**Script when I put the clearing code into the checkSheet function (sends email but doesn't clear)**

```
function onEdit(e) { // Gets called once an edit is made. B6 is the dropdown menu.
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B6') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      e.range.clear({ formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true });
      eval(e.value)();      
    }
  }
}

function print() { // Calls checkSheet() because else it does not work. I do not know why it doesn't work without print()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkSheet").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onEdit().create();
}
  
function checkSheet() { // Creates PDF and sends mail
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/edit");
  const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E4").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();
  const subject = 'Varebestilling' +Date();
  const body = "Varebestilling" +Date();
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-jblLYzQm2lpfY7nb2PUc-zMtWJRs--Gi-tuvsdqcM/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' + 
    '&fitw=true' + 
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false' + 
    '&gid=0'; 
 
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf", //add ss
      content: response.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    }]
         
  });

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rangesToClear = ['B12:B17', 'B20:B25', 'B29:B34'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent(); 
  }
}
```

How do I get it to send the email **and then** clear the neccesary ranges?

Answer (score 2):

This last bit on your last code:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rangesToClear = ['B12:B17', 'B20:B25', 'B29:B34'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent(); 
  }
}
```

SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); will get you the SPREADSHEET and not the actual active sheet. Change this to:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
```

You can test this with a console.log If you run this little script below you will see you get the Spreadsheet file name.

```
function test(){
 console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName()); 
  
}
```

Comment: You can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` as well.

Comment: Also as a side note to this answer, if you want to clear after sending email do the changed suggested by this answer and use the ```checkSheet``` function.